# Why cannot I format the font color as white

Tags: css

Please refer to the screenshot below, I need to change the font of the accordion heading to white. The code works well in "fiddle",but when I embedded the CSS snippet to a SharePoint 2013 page, the font color is not rendered correctly.

```
.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  background-color: #00008B;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8000000;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your dev tools screenshot already shows what rule is overwriting the color ...

Comment: you can use `color: white !important`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have style overriding yours so you can be more specific like this :

```
a.accordionTitle,
a.accordion__Heading {
  background-color: #00008B;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8000000;
}
```

Or use important like this :

```
.accordionTitle,
.accordion__Heading {
  background-color: #00008B;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white!important;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8000000;
}
```

You may read more about [Specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and for sharing the knowledge!

Comment: @TZhang welcome ;) don't forget to mark answer as accpeted if it solve your issue